# Microsoft Access AND MYSQL Data Types comparision

Tags: mysql, sql

What is equivalent to dataType **LONG** IN  **MYSQL.**  As i have seen in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp. The **long** is **Microsoft Access Data Types** .I want to know what can be used instead of **LONG IN MYSQL.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and int, that is the same Datatype as you can see in the page you have provided.

MS Access:

> Long   Allows whole numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647

MySQL:

> INT(size)  -2147483648 to 2147483647 normal. 0 to 4294967295
>   UNSIGNED*. The maximum number of digits may be specified in
>   parenthesis